# Зависает WebApp на iOS 17.x при нажатии мимо выпадающего меню

Tags: javascript, html, ios, telegram, html-select

Всем привет, пробую писать бота на python с библиотекой aiogram, создал inline клавиатуру с webapp
В разметке кода страницы есть

На ПК и на Андроиде все работает без проблем, тыкается куда нужно, ничего не зависает
На устройствах iOS 17.x возникает проблема:
Если раскрыть список и пока он открыт тыкнуть или свайпнуть в другом месте, то вся страница зависает, релоад через 3 точки не помогает. Спасает только закрытие WebApp и открытие заново нажатием по инлайн кнопке.

Миску риса осведомленным, дайте совет, пожалуйста.

Пробовал в js вставлять element.blur() по советам из интернетов, делать невидимый блок на фоне, запрещать скролл, делать body { position: fixed } в css. Ничего не спасло.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант переписать список из условного `<ul>` в `<div>` (можно найти такую реализацию на codepen) и при открытии такого списка вешать на все остальные блоки, кроме самого списка (представим, что выпадающий список у нас имеет class="selector", а все остальное находится в class="main", без использования body). Тогда можно будет отлавливать event onclick на body и отсекать нажатие на список, а если нажимают мимо списка - закрывать его.

Comment: Я думал об этом варианте, но в реализации нужно подтягивать листы, условно словари, в которых суммарно 3к значений.
Там есть выбор города, и городов 200+. При реализации через <ul> получается длиннющая шторка на 2 метра вниз.

Comment: Выпадающий список из примера можно ограничить по размеру, подставить тоже проблем не будет (jinja2 + context), но тут решать вам)